# Convert rigged armature into static object

Tags: rigging

For 3d printing purposes, can I turn a rigged armature into a static object? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and apply the armature in the modifier's tab. There should be a button named "Apply".

If you're looking for a specific pose, just get the pose that you want and hit "Apply" and your mesh will get that pose permanently.

Answer (score 0):

If you "apply" your armature modifier and delete your armature, and if your object goes back to it´s original size this is what you do:
Apply armature modifier. 
Select model
Press Alt+P (unparent - keep transforms).
Voilá. Posed model with no armature.