# Convert skinned character in a pose frame to static geometry with Blender python API

Tags: python, modifiers, rigging, armature

Given a character with rigged armature that has animation of 30 frames, how can I convert it to 30 static meshed, each with their pose applied?
I found an answer applying the armature of pose in [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119294/convert-rigged-armature-into-static-object), where current pose can be retrieved by applying armature modifier and removing the armature.
However, I am wondering if this can be automated with Blender API?

Comment: [related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122230/lofting-can-i-copy-a-shape-keyed-mesh-for-each-frame-of-its-animation) is a blender 2.79ish method. recently posted modifications required for 2.8x+ on https://blenderartists.org/t/script-convert-from-2-79-to-2-9/1299273

Comment: also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender  and via a mesh cache https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191404/how-do-i-create-a-cachefile-object-for-a-mesh-sequence-cache-modifier